# Device not supported in Android Market

Tags: google-play, android

I've just uploaded my app to the android market place and it works on my Samsung Mini, but when trying to download it to a Samsung Galaxy I get the error message device not supported.

The app is listed with

```
API level: 10-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
Required device features:
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

Any ideas why it doesn't support the Samsung Galaxy phone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned minimum sdk version & also target sdk version in your manifest file ? 
Also android Os version of both the devices are same?

Comment: Hi, I have this in the manifest file: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

Comment: what is android os version on both the devices?